# Property 'subcribe' does not exist on type 'observable<any>' in ionic 3

Tags: php, angular, ionic-framework

How do i fix this error?
[first page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qHzho.png)

[How do i correct the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AJIX3.png)

Comment: Could you replanning the question? you must show the code of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Ty by writting **subscribe** instead of **subcribe**